# Does this function act a bit like a singleton?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I found the `Pages` with a static `getPages<>()` method.

```
class Pages
{
    private static T getPages<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var page = new T();
        PageFactory.InitElements(Browsers.getDriver, page);
        return page;
    }
    public static Home Home => getPages<Home>();
    public static Dashboard Dashboard => getPages<Dashboard>();
    public static Profile Profile => getPages<Profile>();
}
```

The way I work with this `Pages` class is as follow:

```
 Pages.Dashboard.IsAt();
 Pages.Profile.GoTo();
 Pages.Profile.IsAt();
```

I'm trying to understand what is happening in the `getPages<>()` function.

When I do for example:

Each time I call `Pages.Dashboard.IsAt();` does it make a new instance of `Dashboard` or just a single instance?

Comment: Yeah it makes and returnes a new one, it's not a singleton

Comment: Object instances are singletons, not functions. In this case all properties end up calling the function and returning a new result.

Comment: You could create a singleton *very* easily with `static readonly Home Home{get;} = getPages<Home>();`. Use assignment, not an expression-bodied member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes and returns a new instance, but the way to access this getter is a static method.

The property "Dashboard" is static, that means that you can access it from the class definition and you do not need an instance of the "Pages" class to get to it.

But because the property is a getter that runs a function, and because that function returns a new instance every time, you end up with a new instance each time.